# python3 to python2 openfile backporting

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to convert some code from python3 to python2. I have this statement on py3:

```
    with open(self.domFile, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        self.domInput = self._read_input(file)
```

I tried like in python 2 tutorial:

```
    import codecs
    with codecs.open(self.domFile, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        self.domInput = self._read_input(file)
```

I tried like in other resources:

```
    from io import open
    with open(self.domFile, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        self.domInput = self._read_input(file)
```

I tried like with native py2 style:

```
    with open(self.domFile, "r") as source:
        file = source.read().encode("utf8")
        self.domInput = self._read_input(file)
```

the result is not simular like in python 3. I need to parse PDDL file (I don't think that it is important).

Comment: What went wrong? Some error (post it, please)? Didn't decode properly? Computer exploded in ball of fire (pics, please)?

Comment: Thank you for posting exactly what you tried though, good job for a first question :)

Comment: interpreter didn't make any warnings or exceptions, but finite files are not the same in python 3 encoding and python 2